# Should I edit reviewer quotes (typos, etc.) in a response to reviewers?

Tags: peer-review

I am writing a response to reviewers. One reviewer's comments included typos and other incorrect English phrasing, but the intent of the reviewer's points was clear.

When I reproduce or quote the reviewer in my formal response, should I correct these minor errors? I don't want the editor or other reviewers to think that I made the mistakes.

And if I do correct the errors, should I say anything about how the quoted portions included minor edits? I don't want to "correct" the reviewer (and it's really not necessary), but I also don't want to be seen as changing what the reviewer said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put yourself in the editor’s perspective:
They want to go through the reviewer’s points one by one and see whether you addressed them, having the reviewer’s comments available for comparison. They cannot rely on your interpretation of the reviewer’s comments but need to refer to the original. Suppose you misunderstood the reviewer’s intentions at some point. If you distort the quote, this is causing a lot of confusion. At worst, you evoke the appearance of cheating yourself through peer review by tricking the editor into thinking that the reviewer wrote something more benign than they actually did. Even if you make clear that you changed the quotes, this causes extra work as the editor has to refer to the original report when in doubt. (Or they just return it immediately and request that you quote accurately.)

Something similar holds for the reviewer’s perspective. If they get to see your response to them, any misquote may cause confusion or worse. They will probably also not be happy about you nitpicking their language.

The general paradigm of never distorting quotes without marking this applies here as well. And if your quotes of the reviewer are riddled with square brackets, this will arise suspicions.

The only reason where I would change a quote (with a mark) is if the reviewer made an obvious mistake in a reference or quoting your manuscript, where the exactness is crucial to understanding what happened and it would be overkill to write an extra sentence like: “We presume the reviewer meant …”. For example, I once received a minor comment along the lines of this:

> Change “stochasticity” to “stochasticity” in line 42.

Taken as it is, this doesn’t make much sense. However, in line 42, I had written “stochast**s**icity”. Thus my reply went:

> > Change “stochast[s]icity” to “stochasticity” in line 42.
>
> Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest not making corrections, but quoting the review as necessary. If the reviewer report is understandable, then no corrections are necessary, as it won't be published.

You probably have more important concerns and more important uses for your time.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit** in response to  comment from @Wrzlprmft

I think that's right. I will leave this answer up so future visitors can see what might have been their first thoughts.

---

You are addressing the editor, not the reviewer. The reviewer may never see what you say.

I suggest that you write your responses to the reviewer's comments by paraphrasing those comments, then what you have done with them (make changes, disagree, ...). That bypasses the problem of "correcting the reviewer".

If you do need a direct quote, don't correct it. The editor can see and ignore the typos as well as you can.

Comment: I would strongly advise against paraphrasing the reviewer as a main means of reproducing their statements. You may unintentionally distort them and the editor cannot rely on this anyway and would have to double-check with reviewer’s original report. The editor usually wants to see the entire report (except parts that obviously do not demand a response) quoted interspersed with your responses so they can see whether you addressed them and what conflicts, etc. are remaining. Many journals explicitly require this format.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You're right. See me edit.